# Remove ipynb_checkpoints from binary model in notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to run a binary model in notebook, and it seems I'm getting .ipynb_checkpoints showing up as a class. I'm not sure if I changed a setting in Jupyter or what's happening, but I'm getting 3 classes for all the binary models I'm running.

Any ideas? My coworker suggested: using pathlib.unlink() in Jupyter.

But I'm never used pathlib so I'm not sure of the proper code to get it to run.

I'm not 100% sure what's happening, and I've been trying to go into the virtual environment and adding a .gitignore file that contains:
.ipynb_checkpoints
*/.ipynb_checkpoints/*

Still getting .ipynb_checkpoints as a class.
Any ideas?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7piH.png)

Comment: the checkpoints are caches of the notebooks' state and are in the file system. they aren't a python class. i bet you can configure jupyter to not create them, but why would you want that?

Comment: also, can you explain your second image? what are we supposed to take away from that?

Comment: (adding it to .gitignore means that git won't track it, not that it won't exist in the file system)

Comment: it seems irrelevant that they're being created. If you really want to get rid of them just try `rm`ing them.

Comment: Sorry, I picked the wrong screenshot, my bad. I did try rm in terminal, it just keeps popping up. Long time lurker, first time poster. When I run train_generator or test generator I still get as an output:
Found 345 images belonging to 3 classes.
Out[5]:
{'.ipynb_checkpoints': 0, 'Covid': 1, 'Non-Covid': 2}

I've tried 'rm -r .ipynb_checkpoints/' in terminal and it temporarily removes the checkpoints, until I run the notebook and the class shows up again. I think it may have sometime to do with imagegenerator maybe.

Comment: It's not a big issue to have checkpoint, but it's interfering with binary classes. Ugh even older notebooks of Dog v Cat, etc.